# Access to class fields with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a directed graph on which I have to find the shortest path that passes from a given set of nodes. To do this, I am looking for the permutations on this set and for each of it, I compute the length summing the shortest path between each pair of nodes. I have a variable taking count of the shortest permutation and length found so far.

Until I have to deal with 10 nodes, I manage to check all the permutations in 1s, afterwards there is a bottleneck for this reason I would like to use multiprocessing.Pool().

The problem is that I have to read and write variables of the class in which Pool.imap is called.

This is the code that I am using without multiprocessing/multithreading.

This code is contained in the method createRoute(self) of class Area.

```
#This returns a list of nodes as integers
binsToEmpty = self.calculateBinsToEmpty() 

minLength = float("inf")
minPath = None

allPermutationsOfPaths = permutations(binsToEmpty)

for p in allPermutationsOfPaths:
    readElem = iter(p)
    next(readElem)

    length = 0
    for a,b in izip(p, readElem):
        if length < minLength:
            #getShortestLength returns an integer
            length += self.getSorthestLength(a._id, b._id)
        else:
            break

    #Every path starts and ends at node 0 which is not included in the permutation        
    length += self.getSorthestLength(0, p[0]._id)
    length += self.getSorthestLength(p[-1]._id, 0)

    if length < minLength:
        minLength = length
        minPath = p
```

I tried to figure out the workaround from similar questions but I haven't understood how to implement it.

Comment: You probably want to look for a faster algorithm, like breadth-first search, Dijkstra or A-star, instead of parallelizing an extremely slow solution.

Comment: Sounds like you want a solution to the travelling salesman problem. Google that.

Comment: I am already using Dijkstra, the problem is how to combine the results of the Dijkstra between two nodes in order to optimise the path.